# keep google cloud shell files outside of $HOME directory

Tags: google-cloud-shell

My Python Modules And Installed Packages Get Deleted after session Restart. Any Workaround?

Expected: To The Files To Be Saved.

Also I Would Like The Session To Be Online 24/7 If Anyone Knows How, Thanks In Advamced For Answering My Post

Comment: This is not the purpose of Cloud Shell (it is ephimeral *by design*). Why don't use Compute instances?